# Tiles 2.2 put-list-attribute + Spring 3.1.4

Tags: spring, jstl, tiles

I am migrating our application from struts 1.3 to spring 3.1.4 mvc. In the process i am also upgrading from tiles 1.1 to tiles 2.2. Jstl version is 1.1. With Tiles 2.2, i am having an issue about using put-list-attribute. I am trying to show a simple jsp page which should does following:
a) Header : include bunch of css (i commented it out as it doesn't work. Using firebug i see error `"NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://localhost:8080/appname/%BeachStyle%7d"    --- {eachStyle}`
No idea where %BeachStyle% came from.
b) Header : include title -- `Works fine`
c) body   : show static text

tiles.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.1//EN"
"http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_1.dtd">

<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name=".login" preparer="com.tiles.LoginController"
    template="/tiles/layouts/layoutmain.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="pageTitle" value="vivi test" />
    <put-list-attribute name="baseStylesTest">
        <add-attribute value="/styles/css/grids.css"/>
        <add-attribute value="/styles/css/superfish.css"/>
        <add-attribute value="/styles/css/styles.css"/>
    </put-list-attribute>

    </definition>
</tiles-definitions>
```

layoutmain.jsp

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" prefix="tiles" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn"%> 
<tiles:useAttribute id="stylesList" name="baseStylesTest" classname="java.util.List"/>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <%-- <c:forEach var="eachStyle" items="${baseStylesTest}">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<c:out value='${eachStyle}'/>"    /> --%>
    <title><tiles:insertAttribute name="pageTitle" /> </title>
</head>
<body>
    Login page body
</body>
</html>
```

I tried the following:
i) Checked the tiles2.2 dtd and example to use it - found similar usage
ii) Checked examples over internet and how it's being used - found similar usage
iii) Checked how its used with struts -- found they use #attr.xxx as it is in pagescope

I don't see anything wrong in my implementation. The title attribute is rendered properly but on the attribute belonging to put-list-attribute.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I investigated more and i found that JSTL is not rendering the properties. For example, ${baseStylesTest} doesn't work. However if i use something like <spring:message code="${title}"/>, it works.

Comment: More specs: Server Info: Apache Tomcat/5.5.27
Servlet Version: 2.4
Jsp Version: 2.0
Java Version: 1.6.0_37

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. JSTL wasn't working as i declared my web-app version to be 2.5. This is not compatible with tomcat5.5 which i was using. Changed the web-app version to be 2.4 and all is good.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

---

</web-app>
```